# Looping through a List<string[]> and get values of it

Tags: c#, arrays, list, razor, arraylist

I am trying to display the values of this list of arrays, the problem is that the values are not displaying in the browser. I have the values of the list/arrays.
I don't know the problem or what's wrong with the syntax, any advice?

```
               @{
                    List<string[]> validate_rules = new List<string[]>();
                    if (TempData["verification_errors"] != null)
                    {
                        validate_rules = (List<string[]>)TempData["verification_errors"];
                    }
                }

                @foreach (var item in validate_rules)
                {
                    <label >@item[0].ToString() @item[2].ToString()</label>
                }
```

Comment: The exact shame question was posted today/yesterday... Is this from some tutorial? or homework? Remove the `(` and add the `@` also infront of `item[2]`

Comment: How have you confirmed that there are elements in the list at all?  What debugging have you done?  What is the *exact* output from this?  It also seems suspect to me that this entire thing is wrapped in a `@{}` code block.  What happens when you just use a simpler inline syntax?

Comment: is that *razor* ? It should be tagged so.

Comment: @hashim : double posting your question is **strongly discouraged*** here.

Comment: Please explain how this question is not the same as your previously posted one

Comment: it is not the same because the problem is different same code with different problem

Comment: here the problem is i got the values but it is not display in the browser their the problem for how to get the values ??!

Comment: @hashim - you haven't even updated your code with the solution you got.. Also when you say there is a problem explain what the problem is and what you have tried

Comment: @GiladGreen the previous question and problem was solved and i marked the question with the right answer , what is the problem with my question ??!

Comment: @GiladGreen i explained the problem is the values i got it from array-list is not display in the browser , i mean i have values from the array list but in  this line should display in the browser ? `<p>@(item[0].ToString() + " " + item[2].ToString())</p>`

Comment: Have you debugged? Store it in a temp string and see what it contains

Comment: yes i debugged and i see the values

Comment: also when i put `<p>test</p>` for test inside for-each loop not display also

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You've surrounded the entire thing in a [Razor Code Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor#razor-code-blocks).  From the documentation:

> Unlike expressions, C# code inside code blocks is not rendered.

I'm surprised it's even syntactically valid with the inline HTML inside a code block like that, unless there's an error that you're just ignoring.  Remove the output from the code block.  Something like this:

```
@{
    List<string[]> validate_rules = new List<string[]>();
    if (TempData["verification_errors"] != null)
    {
        validation_rules = (List<string[]>)TempData["verification_errors"];
    }
}
@foreach (var item in validation_rules)
{
    <p>@(item[0].ToString() + " " + item[2].ToString())</p>
}
```

The output can probably even be simplified to this:

```
@foreach (var item in validation_rules)
{
    <p>@item[0] @item[2]</p>
}
```

Comment: i updated my code with your answer but still have the problem ?!

Comment: any advice for this issue ?

Comment: @hashim: Can you update the question with your current code?  Also, how have you confirmed that the list has any elements at all?

Comment: i debugged all elements and it has values for all elements

Comment: @hashim: *How?*  When you're asking us why your code isn't working, assuring us that you've checked and that we should just take your word for it that it's working doesn't exactly help.  Don't assume that everything you've done is right, validate it.

Comment: @hashim: I've just tested your exact code (updated from this answer) in a view and it works fine.  It would seem that the problem is something else.  Perhaps your list has no elements, or isn't in the `TempData` in the first place, or some other problem.  But the code works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153797/discussion-between-hashim-and-david).